# How add total value of a field as a pre-aggregated field in update time MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I know that using $inc in Mongo you can calculate and update the count of data in update time, such as:

```
db.flights.update(  
  {
     $inc: {totalCnt: 1}
     $push: { price: {'t': time, 'p': newValue },
     $setOnInsert: { flightNo: "EN120" , airline="LFT"}
  },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

However, I need to also calculate the total value of **price.p** (in above example) and add and store it as a field in update time. I wondering is it possible to use $sum or $add in update?
(Actually I want to be able to store average price as pre-aggregated field in update time).

For example, suppose that this document exists in flights collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "flightNo" : "EN120", "airline" : "LFT", "price" : [{"t": 120, "p": 2500}]}
```

The result that I need after executing update (suppose new value for time and price is **130** and **3000** respectively) command is:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "flightNo" : "EN120", "airline" : "LFT", "price" : [{'t': 120, 'p': 2500}, {'t': 130, 'p': 3000}], "totalCnt":2, "totalPrice": 5500}
```

And after executing another update with **t=150** and **p=2850** the result should be:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "flightNo" : "EN120", "airline" : "LFT", "price" : [{'t': 120, 'p': 2500}, {'t': 130, 'p': 3000}, {'t': 150, 'p': 2850}], "totalCnt":3, "totalPrice": 8350}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you add documents and expected result from that documents.

Comment: @turivishal I added an example. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Mongo v4.2+ you can use [pipelined update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), mind you you'll have to change your updates structure like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { query },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                airline: {$ifNull: ["$airline", "LFT"]},
                flightNo: {$ifNull: ["$flightNo", "EN120"]},
                price: {$concatArrays: [{$ifNull: ["$price", []]}, [{'t': time, 'p': newValue}]]},
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                totalPrice: {
                    $reduce: {
                        input: "$price",
                        initialValue: 0,
                        in: {$sum: ["$$this.p", "$$value"]}
                    }
                },
                totalCnt: {$size: "$price"}
            }
        }
    ],
    {
        upsert: true
    }
)
```

For lesser versions you'll have to split it into 2 calls. first fetch, do the calculation in code and then update.

--- EDIT ---

A more efficient way of calculating `totalPrice`:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { query },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                flightNo: {$ifNull: ["$flightNo", "EN120"]},
                totalPrice: {$sum: ["$totalPrice", newValue]},
                price: {$concatArrays: [{$ifNull: ["$price", []]}, [{'t': time, 'p': newValue}]]},
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                totalCnt: {$size: "$price"}
            }
        }
    ],
    {
        upsert: true
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tom Slabbaert. It seems nice solution. I just wondering in this solution, it calculates the sum of all old existing prices for every new update or it only add new value to previous totalPrice and update it? (I just wondering about the update performance time)

Comment: Does anyone else have another solution?

Comment: You're right, i edited in the more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear @Tom Slabbaert. I think it is efficient enough. However, still there is a problem. Actually, I want to insert flight information if the flightNo dose not exist in collection. If the flightNo exists in collection, I just want to push its price's changes over the time. In the other word, my collection is like as time series database which each flight's price changes over the time should be stored in "price" field. In your proposed solution, you check if flightNo is null, the it will be set as "EN120".

Comment: `evaluates to a null value, including instances of undefined values or missing fields` it's not just `null` value. i'm checking to see if the field exists.

Comment: Great, what about other fields? for example I should check if flightNo="EN120" dose not exist, some other fields like as DestinationAirport, DepartureAirport, Airline end etc should be inserted too? @Tom Slabbaert

Comment: yes, they weren't part of your code snippet but obv whatever you want saved should be added.

Comment: Thanks, I have added "airline" to my example. Would you please update your solution to show how should I add "airline" to update? Actually, I should check if flightNo='EN120' dose not exist, then flightNo='EN120' and airline='LFT' should be inserted. And, if lightNo='EN120' exists, only time and price should be pushed into "price" array of corresponding flight and "totalPrice" updated. Thanks a lot. @Tom Slabbaert.

Comment: Would you please tell me how can I calculate and update the minimum value of prices for each flight? I used $min like as $sum, but the result was not correct. Thanks. @Tom Slabbaert

Comment: You can either do `$min` combined with `$map` first use map to make `[{t: time, p: price}, {t: time2, price: price2}]` into `[price, price2 ...]` then you could use `$min`. the alternative is using `$reduce` and choosing the min between the two values.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tom Slabbaert. Again, can I ask you please update your code example with best solution for $min? Thanks